# Multiple Elifs based on Different Factors

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, calendar, list-comprehension

I have a pands df with int columns year, month, and day. I would like to create a new column df.is_payday, in the most pythonic way possible, that is a 1 whenever df.day is 20 or 30, else 0.

However, some months don't have 30 days, so in those cases I would like df.is_payday to have a 1 only when df.day is 20 or 29 else 0.

However, some months don't even have 28 days, so in those cases I would like df.is_payday to have a 1 only when df.day is 20 or 28 else 0.

Could that be done with list comprehension? Can this also be done using the calendar or datetime modules based on some count of month days?

EDIT

I have successfully used the below code although I would love to use something more pythonic:

```
lst = []
for i,k in zip(df['day'], df['month_total_days']):
    if i == 20 | i == 30 & k >= 30:
        lst.append(1)
    elif i == 20 | i == 29 & k == 29:
        lst.append(1)
    elif i == 20 | i == 28 & k == 28:
        lst.append(1)
    else:
        lst.append(0)
df['is_payday'] = lst
```

Comment: I used the following and this worked, however I would love to use something more pythonic: lst = []
for i,k in zip(df['day'], df['month_total_days']):
    if i == 20 | i == 30 & k >= 30:
        lst.append(1)
    elif i == 20 | i == 29 & k == 29:
        lst.append(1)
    elif i == 20 | i == 28 & k == 28:
        lst.append(1)
    else:
        lst.append(0)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to find where `df.day` is equal to 20 and to get the 28, 29, and 30 value depending on the case, it is actually where `df.day` is equal to `df.month_total_days`, except if `df.month_total_days` is over 30, so you can use [`pd.clip_upper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip_upper.html#pandas.Series.clip_upper) for example to have 30 instead of any value over.

```
import numpy as np

df['is_payday'] = np.where( (df.day == 20) | 
                            (df.day == df.month_total_days.clip_upper(30), 1, 0)
```